# Absolute center with jquery return margin-left 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, centering, absolute

I have designed a JQuery plug-in for a website, with the purpose of helping center an element with absolute position, using pixels and not percentage.
When the page starts, elements are centered vertically but not horizontally (margin-left=0). When I use the same script in console, I apply to an element and it works.

Code to append the function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(element).psfCenter();
});
```

Function :

```
(function ($){
    // center element
    $.fn.psfCenter=function(orientation){   
         return this.each(function() {
            var widthParent=$(this).parent().width()/2;
            var heightParent=$(this).parent().height()/2;
            var widthElement=$(this).width()/2;
            var heightElement=$(this).height()/2;
            var left=widthParent-widthElement;
            var top=heightParent-heightElement;
            console.log(orientation)
            switch(orientation){
                case"x":
                $(this).css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'margin-left':left,
                })
                break;

                case "y":
                $(this).css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'margin-top':top
                })
                break;

                default:
                $(this).css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'margin-left':left,
                'margin-top':top
                })
                break;
            }   
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: there is not need to use `margin-*` for absolute positioned element, use `top,left,right or bottom` instead, and detect the position instead of margin.

Comment: don't work... left=0   :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give the element left 50% and than margin-left the half of its width.
This because you probably want to have it working on a smaller device (responsive).

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bsxqmL6f/

```js
$.fn.psfCenter = function(orientation) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var inner_width = self.width();
        var inner_height = self.height();
        var set_absolute = function() {
            self.css('position', 'absolute');
        }        
        var set_left = function() {
            self.css({
                'left': '50%',
                'margin-left': '-' + (inner_width * .5) + 'px'
            }); // faster than deviding by 2
        };
        var set_top = function() {
            self.css({
                'top': '50%',
                'margin-top': '-' + (inner_height * .5) + 'px'
            }); // faster than deviding by 2
        };
        
        set_absolute();
        switch(orientation) {
            case 'x':
                set_top();
                break;
            case 'y':
                set_left();
                break;
            default:
                set_left();
                set_top();
                break;
        }
    });
}

$('.center-me').psfCenter();
```

```css
.center-me {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.huge {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.smaller {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="center-me huge"></div>
<div class="center-me smaller"></div>
<div class="center-me"></div>
```

Comment: Thank's your code don't work verticaly or horizontaly for some elements.
I think i have a problem in my html but i don't know why.
I am not developper only a webdesigner so you teach me about writting some things on object oriented object